# Jqplot Donut Chart Legends getting removed on save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, donut-chart

I am creating a donut chart using jqplot with legends shown in outside grid.
When I try to save the chart as png , in the resulting image legends are coming empty.

```
var imgData = $('#placeholder')
  .jqplotToImageStr({});
tit = "donutChart"
var fileName = tit + '.png'
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = imgData;
downloadLink.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

```js
rend = $.jqplot.DonutRenderer;
pie = [10,20,30,40,50]
                 series = [pie];
                    ticky = [];
                    tickx = [];
                    var myLabels=[],labelTotal=0;
                    $(pie).map(function(){labelTotal += this[1];})
                    myLabels = $.makeArray($(pie).map(function(){return this[1]+ " ("+Math.round(this[1]/labelTotal * 100) + "%)";}));
                    optionsObj = {
                      grid:{background:"#ffffff"},
                            fontFamily: 'sans-serif,arial,verdana',
                            highlighter: {
                                show: true,
                                sizeAdjust: 10,
                                tooltipLocation: 'n',
                                tooltipAxes: 'y',
                                tooltipFormatString: '<b><i><span style="color:#ffffff;">Count:</span></i></b> %d',
                                useAxesFormatters: false
                            },
                            /*cursor: {
                                show: true,
                                zoom: true,
                                looseZoom: true
                            },*/
                            grid:{
                             background:'#ffffff'
                            },
                            legend: {
                             renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer, 
                             rendererOptions: {numberRows : 18,numberColumns:2},
                             location:'e', 
                             seriesToggle : true,
                             show: true,
                                placement: 'outsideGrid'
                            },
                            axes: {
                                xaxis: {},
                                yaxis: {}
                            },
                         seriesDefaults: {
                             renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
                             rendererOptions:{
                               sliceMargin: 1,
                               startAngle: -90,
                               showDataLabels: true,
                               // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
                               // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
                                // "totalLabel=true" uses the centre of the donut for the total amount
                               dragable: {
                                      color: '#ff3366',
                                      constrainTo: 'x'
                                  },
                                  isDraggable: true,
                               totalLabel: true
                             }
                           }
                    }
                    var plot1 = $.jqplot('placeholder', series, optionsObj);
                  
                    
 $("#save").on("click",function(){
  var imgData = $('#placeholder').jqplotToImageStr({});
            tit="donutChart"
            var fileName=tit+'.png'
            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = imgData;
            downloadLink.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink); 
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div id="placeholder" style="width:300px;height:300px">

</div>
<button id="save">
Save Image
</button>
```

[image: Jqplot chart][image: png image generated]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include script enhancedPieLegendRenderer.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.enhancedPieLegendRenderer.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still not working. I included the file and changed {renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer} to {renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedPieLegendRenderer, }

Comment: This is my [jsFiddle Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ykxft9a8/) I couldn't findthe specified file in cdn. In my local I have tried by including the same. It didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Is there any other fix?